# is there an easy way to add municipal, education, and education requisition numbers together to get total?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, subquery

I want to add municipaltax, education, and education requisition allowance together as simply as possible.

How can I shorten this?

```
'municipaltax' = epa.assessed_value \* (select tax_rate from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type = 'municipal' and tax_year = 2022)

'education' = epa.assessed_value \* (select tax_rate from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type = 'education' and tax_year = 2022)

'education requisition allowance' = epa.assessed_value \* (select tax_rate from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type = 'education requisition allowance' and tax_year = 2022)

'total tax' = (epa.assessed_value \* (select tax_rate from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type = 'municipal' and tax_year = 2022)) +
(epa.assessed_value \* (select tax_rate from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type = 'education' and tax_year = 2022)) +
(epa.assessed_value \* (select tax_rate from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type = 'education requisition allowance' and tax_year = 2022))
```

Comment: you can select the first three vlues in a cte and the use the result to get the total., but an easya way it isn't

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just looking for

```
epa.assessed_value * (select sum(tax_rate) from EdmontonPropertyTaxRate where tax_rate_type in ('municipal','education','education requisition allowance') and tax_year = 2022)
```

but you should give some thought to how you want it rounded; if each separate tax amount should be rounded to cents, you can't just add all the rates together.